# Systemd is unmounting my /boot partition

Tags: mount, boot, systemd

My sda1 is mounted to /boot after booting, and I can manually mount it just fine. But something is automatically unmounting that partition, even after I've manually mounted it.

These are the current permissions when it's unmounted:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    0 Sep 24 14:15 boot/
```

and when it's mounted:

```
drwxr-x---   4 root root 2.0K Jan  1  1970 boot/
```

Is there supposed to be a discrepancy between these two?

This is what's in /etc/fstab

```
UUID=32AC-72EA          /boot       vfat        nodev,nosuid,noexec,rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro    0 2
```

The UUID is correct, I've checked it.

journalctl:

```
Sep 24 18:45:31 StoraArch systemd[1]: Unmounting /boot...
Sep 24 18:45:31 StoraArch systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot.
```

Comment: Look in syslog? I've once had a similar issue with removable drives, and it turned out to be a udev/systemd issue.

Comment: What init system are you using?

Comment: Seems to be systemd...                                                                              Sep 24 18:45:31 StoraArch systemd[1]: Unmounting /boot...
Sep 24 18:45:31 StoraArch systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot.

Comment: @Nordic: That is why I asked... It sounds like systemd...

Comment: Yeah nice find, I hadn't even thought of journalctl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour, introduced in [systemd 220](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/systemd/systemd/tree/NEWS?id=v220).

[systemd-efi-boot-generator](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-efi-boot-generator.html) automounts your ESP on demand and then automatically unmounts it after 2 minutes of it not being used.