# How to stop systemd from immediately unmounting degraded btrfs volume?

Tags: filesystems, systemd, mount, btrfs

I lost a disk on my RAID1 metadata/RAID6 data btrfs volume (`/backup`). Recovery should start with: `mount -o degraded /backup`, but unfortunately, after doing that, systemd decided to promptly unmount it (from the journal):

```
Jan 21 17:27:02 Jiji systemd[1]: backup.mount: Unit is bound to inactive unit dev-disk-by\x2duuid-b162055b\x2da73c\x2d4958\x2d98a7\x2dc6ad57867506.device. Stopping, too.
Jan 21 17:27:02 Jiji systemd[1]: Unmounting /backup...
Jan 21 17:27:40 Jiji systemd[1]: Unmounted /backup.
```

I tried changing `/etc/fstab` to use the label instead of the UUID, and also running `systemctl daemon-reload`. Unfortunately, systemd continued to immediately unmount it (now with an inactive `dev-disk-by\x2dlabel….device`, though).

Thankfully, it doesn't seem I hit the btrfs degraded mount only once gotcha.

This is immediate, so unlikely an automount timeout (as in [Systemd is unmounting my /boot partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231862/systemd-is-unmounting-my-boot-partition)) and I tried `daemon-reload`, the solution at [Systemd is unmounting my /boot partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231862/systemd-is-unmounting-my-boot-partition).

Unfortunately you can't SIGSTOP pid 1, so that doesn't work .

How can I convince systemd to leave it alone so I can recover my filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a quick fix:

```
systemctl mask backup.mount
```

... which of course will need to be un-done (with `unmask`) once the maintenance is done.

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu 20.04 - systemd keeps unmounting btrfs if it's degraded.